# How to merge two separate c++ code files with make files

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, cmake, point-cloud-library

I have two different source code files
File A.cpp  with CMakeLists.txt and File B.cpp with Makefile. for e.g;

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)       
project(A)
find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED) .....
```

and Makefile as below`

```
OS_NAME ?=$(shell uname)                                                  
LIBS = -lpthread                                                      
LIB_NAME = AdsLib-$(OS_NAME).a                                        
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11                                                
CXXFLAGS += -pedantic                                                 
CXXFLAGS += -Wall                                                            
CXXFLAGS += $(ci_cxx_flags) ifeq ($(OS_NAME),win32)
    LIBS += -lws2_32                       endif                          
    all: example.bin                                                      example.bin: $(LIB_NAME) example.cpp
$(CXX) example.cpp $< $(LIBS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@                          
  test: example.bin
./$<                                                                               
 clean:
rm -f *.o *.bin
```

Goal is to merge the two source code files A.cpp and B.cpp together or lets say to bring the functionality of B.cpp into A.cpp. 
In A.cpp the data acquisition and processing is performed for a sensor and in B.cpp the communication is established between the PC and an embedded PC. 
What I am looking for is to directly communicate from A.cpp to the embedded PC.
To do that I want to merge the make files into a single make file which generates
a single executable.

Comment: What are the contents of B.cpp? Will B.cpp itself also be compiled?, i.e. will you compile A.cpp, B.cpp and C.cpp (C.cpp is the merged file), or just the merged file?

Comment: Wh do you need that? Sounds like a XY problem for me.

Comment: Sounds like your actual question is how to write one make/cmake file to compile both source files at once? Did you already write the code that includes both of them? - You don't need to "merge" source files in order to create a single executable

Comment: yes right a single make/cmake file correct. Now  for each source code file I am having  an separate make file. Individually they complied and executing well.

Comment: @MABVT B.cpp is the file which establish communication between the PC and an embedded PC. preference is to compile only A.cpp with its make file

Comment: IMPORTANT: I do not recommend doing the subsequent stuff, rather rethink what you want to do. Since I think it is good to at least know all evil: Basically it is possible to include .cpp files, which will cause the .cpp's contents to be copied into the target .cpp files. This will most likely spawn a lot of nasty linker errors especially once you start reusing the included .cpp file or compile it itself! So: Write your makefile for A.cpp and in A.cpp include B.cpp. The merge will happen automatically on compilation.